# Transiting in Dubai with two separate tickets (Emirates, Spicejet) - Indian passport without US visa

Tags: usa, india, dubai, emirates, spicejet

I am arriving in Dubai from the US at Terminal 3 at 19:10 with Emirates airline. My onward Spicejet flight is from Terminal 1 the next day at 03:40 AM.

I am an Indian citizen and won't have a valid US visa when I arrive in Dubai. The Emirates website is not letting me apply for a transit visa.

I have luggage and am traveling with family. Please suggest how to apply for a transit visa and baggage transfer.

Comment: As you travel from the US, one might assume you have had a US visa at some point. When did that expire, or what did allow you to stay s legally in the USA? (This is because expired visa sometimes allow for transit without visa or on a transit visa where otherwise you would need a full visa.)

Comment: Have you tried https://www.marhabaservices.com/ae/english/transfer-service ?

Comment: @Willeke : "visa stamp" on my passport expired in March 2023. However, I am still legally allow to stay within US based on the extension of stay received from USCIS.  If I travel outside US I cannot enter without "visa stamp" and immigration authorities across the world need "visa stamp".